# Using outer in R on a matrix valued function

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

Can outer be used to build a block matrix from a matrix valued function?

For example define:

```
f = function(x,y){outer(x,y)}
```

(I want to generalize to when f outputs an arbitrary matrix not just the outer product)
Then I want to create the block matrix created from evaluating f on a list of 2d vectors

For example:

```
input =     
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
x    1    1    2    2
y    1    2    1    2
```

The output would then be a 4x4 matrix:

```
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 2
1 1 4 4
2 2 4 4
```

Where for example the upper left block is f((1,1),(1,1)).

I thought `outer(input,input,f)` might work but it says the dimensions don't match.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want as a result using your small (or an even smaller) example? Might make it easier to guess the right piece of code needed.

Comment: `matrix(aperm(outer(input,input), c(1,2,4,3)), nrow=length(input))` as a stab in the dark?

Comment: I added a small example

Comment: How are the values calculated? You do know that `outer` needs a function which by default is multiplication (`*`) which is being used here.

Comment: Each submatrix is the outer product of two vectors, which I've written as the function f. So in the example the upper left 2x2 block is f((1,1),(1,1)) the upper right is f((1,1),(1,2)), lower left is f((1,2),(1,1)), lower right is f((2,2),(2,2))

Comment: Just help thinking: `l1 <- cbind.data.frame(c(1, 1), c(1, 1), c(1, 2), c(2, 2));l2 <- cbind.data.frame(c(1, 1), c(1, 2), c(1, 1), c(2, 2));L <- Map(outer, l1, l2);rbind(do.call(cbind, L[1:2]), do.call(cbind, L[3:4]))`

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use outer for this so I just used a loop.... Thanks.          l1 <- cbind(c(1, 1), c(1, 2), c(1, 3), c(2, 1), c(2, 2), c(2, 3), c(3, 1), c(3,2),c(3,3));
mat = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol=18)
for(ii in 1:9){
  temp = y(l1[,ii],l1[,1])
  for(jj in 2:9){
    temp = cbind(temp,y(l1[,ii],l1[,jj]))
  }
  mat = rbind(mat,temp)
}
result = mat[3:20,1:18]